# How to export forwardRef with ForwardRefRenderFunction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

I'm having a component which belongs to a UI library, lets call it Input component.
When using this library to call Input, there are many types I can called. For example

```
<Input />
<Input.TextArea />
<Input.Search />
```

Now I want to write a wrapper to this Input component, so I write like this

```
type InputWrapperComponent = FC<InputProps> & {
  Search: typeof Input.Search;
  TextArea: typeof Input.TextArea;
};

const InputWrapper: InputWrapperComponent = (props) => {
  // make some minor changes here
}

InputWrapper.Search = Input.Search;
InputWrapper.TextArea = Input.TextArea;
export default InputWrapper;
```

in **index.tsx**

```
export { default as InputWrapper } from './input';
```

Then I can use them like this:

```
<InputWrapper />. --> Works
<InputWrapper.TextArea />. --> Works
<InputWrapper.Search />. --> Works
```

But by doing this, I cannot use **ref** methods of the original UI library ( something like `inputRef.current.focus()` ). that's why I use **forwardRef** and **ForwardRefRenderFunction** like this

```
type InputWrapperComponent = ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLInputElement, InputProps> & {
  Search: typeof Input.Search;
  TextArea: typeof Input.TextArea;
};

const InputWrapper: InputWrapperComponent = (props, ref) => {
  // make some minor changes here and add the ref to the input
}

InputWrapper.Search = Input.Search;
InputWrapper.TextArea = Input.TextArea;
export default forwardRef(InputWrapper);
```

By changing to this, I can pass the ref to the original UI library and can use its original methods. However, my problem right now is when I change to **forwardRef** and **ForwardRefRenderFunction**, I cannot call **TextArea** and **Search** anymore

```
<InputWrapper />. --> Works
<InputWrapper.TextArea />. --> Error
<InputWrapper.Search />. --> Error
```

This is the error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Anyone can give me some guidance on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is:

1. Define function `InputWrapper` as type `InputWrapperComponent`
2. Define `Search` and `TextArea` as members of `InputWrapper`
3. Create a ref forwarding component with `forwardRef`

The problem is, that `forwardRef` creates a completely new component and does not care, whether there have been some sub-components defined before. They will just be thrown away and you get the error of those members being undefined.

So the way to go is actually:

1. Define function `InputWrapper` as type `InputWrapperComponent`
2. Create a ref forwarding component with `forwardRef`
3. Define `Search` and `TextArea` as members of the new ref forwarding component

Comment: hi Peter, thanks for your answer. I wanna clarify, so based on your suggestion InputWrapperComponent will be defined as ForwardRefRenderFunction (step1). Then in the new ref forwarding component (step2) I have to declare it as ForwardRefExoticComponent right? As I'm using typescript so the eslint require the type of them

Answer (score 2):

I end up using ForwardRefExoticComponent instead of ForwardRefRenderFunction

```
type InputWrapperComponent = React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
  React.PropsWithoutRef<InputProps> & React.RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
> & {
  Search: typeof Input.Search;
  TextArea: typeof Input.TextArea;
  Password: typeof Input.Password;
};
```

But I really not sure whats the difference between them

**Update**: Please check Peter's answer.

For what is the the difference between the two, please check his answer here :
[Whats the difference between ForwardRefExoticComponent and ForwardRefRenderFunction in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237804/whats-the-difference-between-forwardrefexoticcomponent-and-forwardrefrenderfunct)