# Whats the difference between ForwardRefExoticComponent and ForwardRefRenderFunction in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

I'm writing a React component which can forward ref to its chilren

I found out that for the return type of the function components, I can use **ForwardRefExoticComponent** and **ForwardRefRenderFunction**. But I'm not sure whats the difference between them.

So far, When using **ForwardRefExoticComponent**, I can extend it while the **ForwardRefRenderFunction** cannot? I posted a question related to my case here : [How to export forwardRef with ForwardRefRenderFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236857/how-to-export-forwardref-with-forwardrefrenderfunction/64237782#64237782)

If anyone know whats the difference between them and what they do please help me. Because it seems that React team has no document about them (but they are inside react package)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### ForwardRefExoticComponent

The definition taken from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/927f70dd89119f11a47688ed5eb4e0e082bef219/types/react/index.d.ts) is

```
interface ExoticComponent<P = {}> {
    /**
     * **NOTE**: Exotic components are not callable.
     */
    (props: P): (ReactElement|null);
    readonly $$typeof: symbol;
}

interface NamedExoticComponent<P = {}> extends ExoticComponent<P> {
    displayName?: string;
}

interface ForwardRefExoticComponent<P> extends NamedExoticComponent<P> {
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
}
```

If you write it out you get

```
interface ForwardRefExoticComponent<P> {
    /**
     * **NOTE**: Exotic components are not callable.
     */
    (props: P): (ReactElement|null);
    readonly $$typeof: symbol;
    displayName?: string;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
}
```

### ForwardRefRenderFunction

The definition taken from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/927f70dd89119f11a47688ed5eb4e0e082bef219/types/react/index.d.ts) is

```
interface ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, ref: ((instance: T | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<T | null> | null): ReactElement | null;
    displayName?: string;
    // explicit rejected with `never` required due to
    // https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36826
    /**
     * defaultProps are not supported on render functions
     */
    defaultProps?: never;
    /**
     * propTypes are not supported on render functions
     */
    propTypes?: never;
}
```

### Differences

- `ForwardRefRenderFunction` does not support `propTypes` and `defaultProps`, whereas `ForwardRefExoticComponent` does.
- `ForwardRefExoticComponent` has an additional member `$$typeof` of type `symbol`
- The call signature of `ForwardRefRenderFunction` takes a `props` object, which must include a member `children` and a ref object as parameters, whereas the call signature of `ForwardRefExoticComponent` only takes a props object of arbitrary shape as parameter.

### Some more thoughts

The interplay of those two definitions is best seen in the [definition of the `forwardRef` function](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/927f70dd89119f11a47688ed5eb4e0e082bef219/types/react/index.d.ts#L805):

```
function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;
```

Also, a big difference between the two definitions seems to be, that `ForwardRefExoticComponent` (like all exotic components) are no function components, but actually just objects, which are treated specially when rendering them. Therefore the comment

> **NOTE**: Exotic components are not callable.

And for some reason, those exotic components are necessary in some places.

Comment: hi Peter, thanks for your answer. May I have some more of your recommendation. So is it a bad habit when using ForwardRefExoticComponent? Is it better if I just switch to class component instead because I think ref in class component will be more straightforward ?

Comment: If you use `forwardRef` you **must** use `ForwardRefExoticComponent`. It is simply the return type of the function. But to avoid that, there are two ways: you can either switch to class components, where refs are enabled without anything to do as far as I can tell, or you can just define your ref as plain property of the component (which must not be called 'ref' - name it for example 'inputRef', 'compRef', etc.). This works totally fine as well. The only downside of this is, that you can't name your ref 'ref'.

Comment: Is `must include a member children` part still valid in 2022? I see the children prop in PropsWithChildren seems optional https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/927f70dd89119f11a47688ed5eb4e0e082bef219/types/react/index.d.ts#L825